# Nodejs and Streams - A detailed overview?

Tags: node.js, stream

Could anyone please explain to us (just me?) how to use Streams in Nodejs?

This is a follow-up of this: [Compression and decompression of data using zlib in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625251/compression-and-decompression-of-data-using-zlib-in-nodejs)

And my main interest would be to work with files, but also strings (i.e. Stream.toString() and String.toStream()... not real function...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> A stream is an abstract interface implemented by various objects in Node. For example a request to an HTTP server is a stream, as is stdout. Streams are readable, writable, or both. All streams are instances of EventEmitter. ([Streams Documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/streams.html#streams))

This means a Stream is a useful object used by several Node core objects to read and/or write information. The core objects all use this to improve the way you can pipe information from one object to another. Since a Stream is an instance of an EventEmitter your code can be asynchronous and not stall while reading information from somewhere.

```
// imagine 'response' is the output Stream from a client connection
var video = fs.createReadStream("/path/to/video.mpg");
// pipe video to response (while data is being read asynchronously)
video.pipe(response);
```

Check [stream.pipe](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/streams.html#stream.pipe).

For example, to stream a video to an HTTP client while reading it from a file. Or stream an upload to a local file. Use your imagination.

Comment: That's what they meant by stating that something is the instance of EventEmitter i.e. they wanted to declare it's asynchronous ! When you read some stuff and you answer misc questions floating in you head for a while . I'll keep that one . Thanks @dresende