# Why zlib.deflate(buf, callback) is async?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, compression, zlib

When accepting an input buffer, and knowing compression is a CPU bound task, does it needs to offer a callback? Is it just there to follow common practice like `callback(err, result)`?

Doc: http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_deflate_buf_callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compression/decompression is executed in a separate thread and not in the main thread. That is why a callback is needed for when the thread completes its work.

The callback style is the same common signature used throughout node and most third-party modules (error first).

Comment: Here is one sync zip/compression https://github.com/egorFiNE/node-compress-buffer.